# std::forward with pass-by-value argument

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-value, perfect-forwarding

I was reading about encapsulated polymorphism and I came across a piece of code like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct Model<T> : Concept
{
    Model<T>(T impl) :
        mImpl(std::forward<T>(impl))
    {

    }
    virtual Concept* clone() const override
    {
        return new Model<T>(mImpl)
    }

    virtual void operator (const LogMessage::Meta& meta, const std::string& message) override
    {
        mImpl(meta, message);
    }

    T mImpl;
};
```

What is the point of forwarding impl in Model constructor?

Does it make sense to forward an argument if it is passed by value?

Comment: The template argument can be a reference type. With that in mind this `std::forward` makes some sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Model<T>` where `T` is an lvalue reference type (e.g. `X&`) is legal (according to Model's documentation), then `forward` is the correct tool to use here.  Otherwise (if `T` should always be an object type), `move` is the correct tool.

That being said, the `clone` member function makes it look like `T` should only be an object type.  And so `move` would be a better tool to use here.  And in this case `forward` isn't technically wrong, but simply confusing as it raises exactly the question the OP asks.

Comment: thank you for the response, maybe for clarity i should have posted all the article i was reading: [link](http://www.grandmaster.nu/blog/?page_id=158). It was probably a bit too advanced for me, but your answer helped me a lot. Thanks